# Using GeoDjango in model with datetime stamp

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, geodjango

I have model in django which looks like below

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class SignBoard(models.Model):
    location=models.PointField(blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)


class SignBoardData(models.Model):
   signboard=models.ForeignKey(SignBoard,related_name="data")
   content_eng = models.TextField()
   content_hind = models.TextField()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.content_eng

   def __unicode__(self):
         return '%d: %s' % (self.id,self.content_eng)
```

I have enabled postgis extension in my postgresql database.

On migrating the above model.
i get an error .

```
  File "../.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 245, in get_prep_value
    raise ValueError('Cannot use object with type %s for a spatial lookup parameter.' % type(obj).__name__)
ValueError: Cannot use object with type datetime for a spatial lookup parameter.
```

I thought that the datetime field is causing the issue but that's not true.Any idea what may be the cause of it?

Comment: what's the change that you made to the model ?

Comment: @e4c5 I actually didn't chang anything in the model rather I re created the database and migrated fresh and to my surprise, it didn't give error then.

Comment: So, is the problem solved?

Comment: @Udi Yes, though the very cause is not known to me.